# CSS Conflict in Megamenu and default Magento navigation menu

Tags: magento2, less-css, conflict, megamenu

In my project, there is Megamenu implemented and to customization of Megamenu, I have used `custom _module.less` in my theme folder By overriding the Megamenu Folder.

`app->code->RB->Megamenu` (is the Megamenu that i have implemented).which contains its core files (Megamenu module folder)

`app->design->mytheme->RB_Megamenu->web>source->css->_module.less` (In this file i have put customizing Megamenu css)

Now the issue is whenever I disable Megamenu and the default Magento Menu is Enabled, The default Magento menu taking CSS of from Megamenu which creates confliction between two CSS file.

Comment: After disabeling did you deployed static content ? and flushed cache ?

Comment: yes i have deploy static content and also flushed cache as well

Comment: If you want that remove your style when module is disabled, then you have to add your style in your module which is placed at `app->code->RB->Megamenu`, because Magneto will compile all less files which placed in theme folder.

Comment: yes you are right Dipesh,

Answer (score 0):

Can You please Try to put _module.less in your module folder , remove it from theme directory
Place it at `NameSpace >> ModuleName >> view >> frontend >> web >> css >> source >> _module.less`

Clear content of var/cache var/page_cache pub/static and generated/

After that deploy using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I am not sure but there may be name space mistake

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Run below command :

```
php bin/magento clear:cache
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```